# Segmentation fault in simple path finding Code

Tags: c, debugging, path, segmentation-fault, backtracking

I have been trying to debug this code but now really need help at this point. It is  the code for finding a string in a grid but due to some reason I'm getting segmentation fault.Any pointers would be highly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>

char grid[5][5] = {
    {'t', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'd'},
    {'a', 'h', 'n', 'z', 'x'},
    {'h', 'w', 'o', 'i', 'o'},
    {'o', 'r', 'n', 'r', 'n'},
    {'a', 'b', 'r', 'i', 'n'},
};
int n = 5;
int found = 0; // flag indicating if string has been found


void find(int i, int j, char *search) {
    if (i >= n || j >= n || i < 0 || j < 0) {
        return ;
    }

    if (!search) {
        found = 1;
        return ;
    }

    if (grid[i][j] == search[0]) {

        find (i+1, j, search+1); 
        find (i, j+1, search+1);
        find (i+1, j+1, search+1);
        find (i-1, j, search+1);
        find (i, j-1, search+1);
        find (i-1, j-1, search+1);
    }
    else {
        find (i+1, j, search); 
        find (i, j+1, search);
        find (i+1, j+1, search);
        find (i-1, j, search);
        find (i, j-1, search);
        find (i-1, j-1, search);
    }
}


int main() {
    char s[] = {'h', 'o', 'r', 'i', 'z', 'o', 'n', '\0'}; // String to be searched
    find(0, 0, s);
    printf("%s\n", found ? "Found": "Not Found");    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't analysis every step your code will run in. But I think you should check the range of 'search' before using it. Hope it helps

Comment: When coding with c++, check every range of array is a good habit

Comment: If by "check the range" you mean the indices being within the `grid` limits, he *does* do exactly that.

Comment: You need to cache some values, I am sure your recursion is evaluating the same again and again. Try to approach this with Dynamic Programming.

Comment: Also the `else` of `(grid[I][j] == search[0])` seems incorrect. If you are looking for a continuous path, you shouldn't try searching the neighbors if the character doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your implementation is that you haven't written the recursion properly. For continuous path search you shouldn't look at the neighbors if the character doesn't match.

Also second mistake you made is expecting `search` to become NULL when string finishes. Infact you need to check if `search[0] =='\0'`.

Since you don't look at the neighbors(by removing the else), you need to look at all starting points.

Consider the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char grid[5][5] = {
    {'t', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'd'},
    {'a', 'h', 'n', 'z', 'x'},
    {'h', 'w', 'o', 'i', 'o'},
    {'o', 'r', 'n', 'r', 'n'},
    {'a', 'b', 'r', 'i', 'n'},
};
int n = 5;
int found = 0; // flag indicating if string has been found
void find(int i, int j, char *search) {
     if (i >= n || j >= n || i < 0 || j < 0) {
         return ;
     }

     if (search[0]=='\0') {
         found = 1;
         return ;
     }

     if (grid[i][j] == search[0]) {
         find (i+1, j, search+1); 
         find (i, j+1, search+1);
         find (i+1, j+1, search+1);
         find (i-1, j, search+1);
         find (i, j-1, search+1);
         find (i-1, j-1, search+1);
     }
}


int main() {
     char s[] = {'h', 'o', 'r', 'i', 'z', 'o', 'n', '\0'}; // String to be searched
     int i, j;
     for(i = 0; i<n && !found;i++)
         for(j = 0; j<n && !found;j++){
             find(i, j, s);
         }
     printf("%s\n", found ? "Found": "Not Found");    
     return 0;
}
```

This works correctly and prints `Found`.

Demo here : https://ideone.com/l3ohwr

Comment: Thanks..Works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is stack overflow.

If you run your program under debugger, you would see something like this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004006d5 in find (i=3, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:34
34          find (i+1, j, search);
(gdb) bt 10
#0  0x00000000004006d5 in find (i=3, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:34
#1  0x0000000000400720 in find (i=4, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:37
#2  0x00000000004006da in find (i=3, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:34
#3  0x0000000000400720 in find (i=4, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:37
#4  0x00000000004006da in find (i=3, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:34
#5  0x0000000000400720 in find (i=4, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:37
#6  0x00000000004006da in find (i=3, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:34
#7  0x0000000000400720 in find (i=4, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:37
#8  0x00000000004006da in find (i=3, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:34
#9  0x0000000000400720 in find (i=4, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:37
#10 0x00000000004006da in find (i=3, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:34
(More stack frames follow...)
```

Notice that the indices are repeated, and you are not making forward progress. Also this:

```
(gdb) bt -10
#261985 0x0000000000400720 in find (i=4, j=4, search=0x7fffffffdd44 "zon") at t.c:37
#261986 0x0000000000400651 in find (i=4, j=3, search=0x7fffffffdd43 "izon") at t.c:27
#261987 0x0000000000400651 in find (i=4, j=2, search=0x7fffffffdd42 "rizon") at t.c:27
#261988 0x00000000004006f0 in find (i=4, j=1, search=0x7fffffffdd42 "rizon") at t.c:35
#261989 0x00000000004006f0 in find (i=4, j=0, search=0x7fffffffdd42 "rizon") at t.c:35
#261990 0x0000000000400637 in find (i=3, j=0, search=0x7fffffffdd41 "orizon") at t.c:26
#261991 0x0000000000400637 in find (i=2, j=0, search=0x7fffffffdd40 "horizon") at t.c:26
#261992 0x00000000004006da in find (i=1, j=0, search=0x7fffffffdd40 "horizon") at t.c:34
#261993 0x00000000004006da in find (i=0, j=0, search=0x7fffffffdd40 "horizon") at t.c:34
#261994 0x000000000040079f in main () at t.c:46
```

tells you that before the program crashed with stack exhaustion, it managed to (recursively) call `find` 260,000+ times.